# Limit equivalences of x approaching $0^{-}$ or x aprroaching to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How can I show formally the equivalences like below?

$\lim_{x \to -\infty}  \cfrac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} x$

Comment: Let 1/x = u. As x goes to infinity, 1/x goes to zero, so as u goes to zero, it approaches the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac1x=0$ means that given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a number $B<0$ such than

$$-\epsilon<\frac{1}{x}<0$$

whenever $x<B=-\frac1\epsilon$.

---

The statement $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-}x=0$ means that given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a number $\delta<0$ such than

$$-\epsilon<x<0$$

whenever $-\frac1\epsilon<\delta < x < 0$.

---

The equivalences of these statements is evident by enforcing the substitution $x\to 1/x$ and setting $B=1/\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Evaluate the limit on the left side. Then evaluate the limit on the right side. Then compare and notice that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let LHS be $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ and RHS be $\lim_{x\to0^-}{x}$.

Notice that as $x$ in the LHS approaches infinity from the left, $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches closer and closer to $0$. Similarly for RHS, as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left the limit can only be $0$.

You might want to sub in a few values for $x$ to see the trend clearer.